# Where can I get PDF of Srimad Bhagavata by Swami Tapasyananda?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, resource

I am looking for PDF of Swami Tapasyananda's (of Ramakrishna Mission) commentary on Bhagavatam Purana.

Comment: You cant. You can only buy from Google Books if you want

Comment: please rephrase your question.  It looks like you are trying not to pay for intellectual property :-) @rishx

Comment: @SK oh ok. I will try to rephrase my question.